# Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in drupal_validate_utf8()

Tags: 7

I have been getting this error: `Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in drupal_validate_utf8()`.

[image]

After troubleshooting I was able to figure out line that cause this error that is on a **if** stament.

```
  if (empty ($form_state['num_boxes'])) { // Line with the problem.
    $form_state['num_boxes'] = count($boxes) + 1;
  }
```

After researching I believe that have to deal something with [filter_xss_admin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/filter_xss_admin/7). However, it seem unclear to me of how to implement with my code.

**Update 1 - Apparently, the code that I provide did not show the error. I have provide more code.**

```
/**
 * Form builder.
 */
function custom_module_overview_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $boxes = variable_get('custom_module_package_sizes', '');
  if (empty($form_state['num_boxes'])) {
    $form_state['num_boxes'] = count($boxes) + 1;
  }

  $form['sizes']['#prefix'] = '<div id="boxes-fieldset-wrapper">';
  $form['sizes']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_boxes']; $i++) {
    $form['sizes'][$i] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Package'),
      '#description' => t('Enter the dimensions of the packing box.'),
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('physical-dimensions-textfields')),
      '#attached' => array('css' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'physical') . '/theme/physical.css')),
    );

    foreach (physical_dimensions() as $key => $dimension) {
      $form['sizes'][$i][$key] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => filter_xss($dimension)['name'],
        '#size' => 15,
        '#maxlength' => 16,
        '#field_suffix' => '&times;',
        '#prefix' => '<div class="physical-dimension-form-item">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      );

      if (isset($boxes[$i][$key])) {
        $form['sizes'][$i][$key]['#default_value'] = $boxes[$i][$key];
      }
    }
    unset($form['sizes'][$i][$key]['#field_suffix']);

    $form['sizes'][$i]['unit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => physical_dimension_unit_options(FALSE),
      '#prefix' => '<div class="physical-dimensions-unit-form-item">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    if (isset($boxes[$i]['unit'])) {
      $form['sizes'][$i]['unit']['#default_value'] = $boxes[$i]['unit'];
    }
  }

  $form['packing_add_more'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add More'),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="packing-add-more">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#submit' => array('custom_module_admin_add_more_submit'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'custom_module_admin_add_more',
      'wrapper' => 'boxes-fieldset-wrapper',
    ),
  );

  $form['packing_submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#prefix' => '<div class="packing-submit-save">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );

  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');

  return $form;
}
```

**Update 2 - I believe that the issue is in this block**

```
foreach (physical_dimensions() as $key => $dimension) {
          $form['sizes'][$i][$key] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => filter_xss($dimension)['name'], // Removing this line would make the page disappears.
            '#size' => 15,
            '#maxlength' => 16,
            '#field_suffix' => '&times;',
            '#prefix' => '<div class="physical-dimension-form-item">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
          );
```

On the line `'#title' => filter_xss($dimension)['name'],`

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: That error is caused by code that is passing to the form API an array instead of a string. The code you are showing is not causing that error message.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I have updated the question with the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue I had to change this line  `'#title' => filter_xss($dimension)['name'],` to this On the line `'#title' => filter_xss($dimension['name']),`

Answer (score 0):

If your detective work so far is correct, then try this:

```
$form_state['num_boxes'] = strval(count($boxes) + 1);
```

Comment: I don't think this will make a difference. count() always returns an integer. The error says it received an array, which count() never returns.

Comment: @user5482, I have replace `$form_state['num_boxes'] = count($boxes) + 1;` with
`$form_state['num_boxes'] = strval(count($boxes) + 1);` and does not fix the problem.

Comment: yeah, sorry..  @AyeshK is right.  your error is indicating an array is coming in.  I'm going to edit my supplied answer, but it's not going to be a solution... you'll have more digging to do first.

Comment: @user5482, would help if I provide the entire code ?

Comment: @user5482, I have updated the question with the form. Hopefully this would show the error.